# Oracle XMLTable errors with invalid identifier

Tags: oracle, xmltable

What is causing the error: ORA-00904: "DR"."DLR_KEY": invalid identifier?
Oracle Version 12.1.0.2.0

If I comment out the 'left outer join user_dealer...' line then the query runs successfully.

```
select dr.dlr_key,
    dr.dlr_reference_num,
    dr.dlr_name
from dealer dr,
    XMLTable('/DLR' 
        PASSING dr.DLR_DEALER_DATA 
        COLUMNS 
        DlrMiscPymtPlan varchar(100) PATH 'DlrMiscPymtPlan'
        ) as a2
inner join wuser wu on wu.wu_key = 1
left outer join user_dealer ud on ud.udl_dlr_fkey = dr.dlr_key
    and ud.udl_usr_fkey = 1
where (
        UPPER(DLR_NAME) like 'MLB%'
        and (UPPER(a2.DlrMiscPymtPlan) like 'P')
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue deals with how the XMLTable implicitly joins.
This query works:

```
select dr.dlr_key,
    dr.dlr_reference_num,
    dr.dlr_name
from dealer dr left outer join
    XMLTable('/DLR' 
        PASSING dr.DLR_DEALER_DATA 
        COLUMNS 
        DlrMiscPymtPlan varchar(100) PATH 'DlrMiscPymtPlan'
        ) as a2 on 1=1
inner join wuser wu on wu.wu_key = 1
left outer join user_dealer ud on ud.udl_dlr_fkey = dr.dlr_key
    and ud.udl_usr_fkey = 1
where (
        UPPER(DLR_NAME) like 'MLB%'
        and (UPPER(a2.DlrMiscPymtPlan) like 'P')
        )
```

Thanks to information on sites:
[Using join with xmltable](https://odieweblog.wordpress.com/2016/05/20/how-to-using-outer-join-with-xmltable-or-xquery/) and [xmltable with left outer join](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/xmldatabase/entry/the_xmltable_function_and_a_case_where_a_left_outer_join_can_help21?lang=en)